Parola plurale per padri (uomini)
Ho scritto questa frase:
"I genitori di tutti i personaggi sono assenti."
Nella storia a cui mi riferisco ci sono alcuni personaggi con la madre assente, altri con la madre presente, ma nessuno di loro ha un padre, cioè un genitore maschio, presente. Questa frase comunica efficacemente quell’idea? Non credo. Da quello che ho capito, "padre" come parola singolare si riferisce più chiaramente a un uomo, mentre "padri" al plurale può parlare di coppie di entrambi i sessi. Ma non esiste un modo conciso ed efficace per parlare di pluripadri, escludendo dalla categoria le madri?

Il concetto di "padri" in significato più largo, a mio parere, non ha a che fare con la genealogia, ma più con aspetti socio-culturali. Potremmo approfondire sul significato sociale di "padre" (che, per ragioni storiche, è praticamente sempre riferito a persone di genere maschile), ma in questo caso non mi sembra che il dubbio sia legittimo: "i padri di tutti i personaggi" indica abbastanza chiaramente che si riferisce alle persone di genere maschile nella coppia genitoriale.

Non ho mai sentito usare padre come sinonimo di genitore. Hai qualche riferimento a quest'uso? Io scriverei "I padri di tutti i personaggi sono assenti"...

“Padre” è per definizione “Uomo che ha generato uno o più figli” (https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/padre/). Quindi se vuoi parlare di genitori di entrambi i sessi usa “genitori”; se come mi pare di capire ti riferisci solo ai genitori maschi, usa “padri”. Ti stai forse confondendo con lo spagnolo, in cui padres si può riferire a entrambi i genitori? (Vero, @Charo ?)
